# getting a nicely nested and grouped hash based on a SELECT query from postgresql in Ruby

Tags: ruby, select, hash

I have a SELECT query from Postgresql that returns a result that looks like this:

```
 brand | model| firmware | direction | mbps 
-------+------+----------+-----------+------
 Cisco | 7602 | 7.2      | up        | 283
 Cisco | 7602 | 7.3      | up        | 192
 Cisco | 7602 | 7.2      | down      | 200  
 Cisco | 7602 | 7.3      | down      | 107 
 Cisco | 7602 | 7.2      | bi        | 249  
 Cisco | 7602 | 7.3      | bi        | 151
```

I'd like to get the result in a nicely nested hash that would group the brand, model, firmware and then show the mbps value for each direction.
I wanted to show the example of the nested hash but am kind of overwhelmed right now and don't even know how to correctly construct it.

Currently the hash that I get out of running that query looks like this:

```
{"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.2", "direction"=>"up", "mbps"=>"283"}
{"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.3", "direction"=>"up", "mbps"=>"192"}
{"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.2", "direction"=>"down", "mbps"=>"200"}
{"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.3", "direction"=>"down", "mbps"=>"107"}
{"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.2", "direction"=>"bi", "mbps"=>"249"}
{"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.3", "direction"=>"bi", "mbps"=>"151"}
```

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: You need to show how you issue the request to Postgres. It looks like you're doing it from the command-line, rather than using the driver, or preferably an ORM like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html). Using Sequel makes it easy to get the data as a hash as that's its natural object used to represent a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up the groupings like this

```
rows = [{"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.2", "direction"=>"up", "mbps"=>"283"},
        {"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.3", "direction"=>"up", "mbps"=>"192"},
        {"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.2", "direction"=>"down", "mbps"=>"200"},
        {"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.3", "direction"=>"down", "mbps"=>"107"},
        {"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.2", "direction"=>"bi", "mbps"=>"249"},
        {"brand"=>"Cisco", "model"=>"7602", "firmware"=>"7.3", "direction"=>"bi", "mbps"=>"151"}]
data = {}
rows.each do |row|
  data[row['brand']] ||= {}
  data[row['brand']][row['model']] ||= {}
  data[row['brand']][row['model']][row['firmware']] ||= {} 
  data[row['brand']][row['model']][row['firmware']][row['direction']] = row['mbps']
end

puts data
```

outputs:

```
{"Cisco"=>{"7602"=>{"7.2"=>{"up"=>"283", "down"=>"200", "bi"=>"249"}, "7.3"=>{"up"=>"192", "down"=>"107", "bi"=>"151"}}}}
```

Comment: wow, geniuses are wandering in stackoverflow, Thank you so much, that's exactly what I wanted!